# Generating and accessing WSDL on Tomcat with Maven

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, wsdl, jax-ws

I have a JAX-WS server that I package with Maven and deploy on Tomcat. The pom.xml generates the WSDL file automatically with the trick from [Use Maven to trigger a wsgen & wsimport in a row, using wsdlLocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158175/use-maven-to-trigger-a-wsgen-wsimport-in-a-row-using-wsdllocation). I only use the first part, that is:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-wsdl</id>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsgen</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sei>packageName.endpointName</sei>
                <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This is the generated WSDL:

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="NAMEServerPortBinding_MTOM_Policy">
    <ns1:OptimizedMimeSerialization wsp:Optional="true" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy/optimizedmimeserialization"/>
</wsp:Policy>
<types>
    <xsd:schema>
        <xsd:import namespace="http://PACKAGE/" schemaLocation="SERVER_schema1.xsd"/>
    </xsd:schema>
</types>
<etc...>
<service name="NAME">
    <port name="NAMEPort" binding="tns:NAMEPortBinding">
        <soap:address location="REPLACE_WITH_ACTUAL_URL"/>
    </port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

My web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>serverName</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>serverName</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/serverName/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

And my sun-jaxws.xml:

```
<endpoints version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime">
    <endpoint implementation="package.ServerEndpoint" name="serverName"
        url-pattern="/serverLink"/>
</endpoints>
```

I have made sure that Tomcat did deploy and start the webserver, I have checked that the WSDL is indeed inside the server in Tomcat, and yet I cannot figure out how to access it so I can go on to finishing the client and testing the whole thing. I've looked at over a dozen tutorials and most of them seem to get to this point and then say "and here some magic happens, you open a browser and this shows up:"

https://www.java2blog.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/WebserviceOutput.gif

The image used is always the same, and indeed I have seen this when working on Glassfish, but I cannot for the life of me figure out what I must do to make it happen on Tomcat. Both the link http://localhost:8080/server-1.0/serverName/serverLink and http://localhost:8080/server-1.0/serverName return a "404 Not Found: Invalid Request". Appending ?wsdl to either one does not change the result. The answer to [accessing wsdl on Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396468/accessing-wsdl-on-tomcat) suggests installing Metro, which I did, unfortunately to no avail.

All code shown is summarized and has variable names changed. If more information is required, I will be happy to provide it.