# Setting a JBoss / Wildfly webservice endpoint correctly (jboss-web.xml)

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, wildfly, endpoint

I made a little SOAP web service using Spring Boot, with the following files (only relevant files are shown):

**WebServiceConfig.Java**

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig {
    

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<MessageDispatcherServlet> messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext context) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet messageDispatcherServlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        messageDispatcherServlet.setApplicationContext(context);
        messageDispatcherServlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean<MessageDispatcherServlet>(messageDispatcherServlet, "/ws/*");
    }

    @Bean(name = "consultas")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema consultasSchema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        definition.setPortTypeName("ConsultasPort");
        definition.setTargetNamespace("http:/site.com/consultas");
        definition.setLocationUri("/ws");
        definition.setSchema(consultasSchema);   
    
        return definition;
    }

    @Bean
    public XsdSchema consultasSchema() {

        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("consultas.xsd"));
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
server.port=9090
```

**Main.Java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
                    
        System.setProperty("org.jboss.logging.provider", "slf4j2");     
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);                
    }
}
```

**Problem description:**

When I run Main.Java from Eclipse, a Tomcat instance is deployed. Visiting the address *http://localhost:9090/ws/consultas.wsdl*. shows the WSDL description file, and SOAPUI is able to consume the web services without a problem.

The problem starts when I pack the .war and deploy it on wildfly-23.0.2.Final. The context root is always set to /soap-web-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.

**Edit 2021 05 17**

I was able to change the WildFly endpoint by creating a jboss-web.xml file in the folder src\main\webapp\WEB-INF, with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_5_1.xsd">
    <context-root>/ws/*</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

**Steps I tried**

I tried setting

to:

- /
- /ws/*

But I'm still unable to reach the endpoint

Any input will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE Months later I just found [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396468/accessing-wsdl-on-tomcat) by accident, answered by user @pascal-thivent

> ...you access the WSDL at:
>
> http://localhost:8080//services/hello?wsdl
> A               B         C       D
>
> ```
> A is the host and port of the servlet container.
> B is the name of the war file.
> C comes from the url-pattern element in the web.xml file.
> D comes from the ending stem of the url-pattern attribute in the sun-jaxws.xml file
> ```